# Inserting data into gridview using asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have recently been involved in a mini-project and am trying to use asp.net with SQL in it. The problem I am facing is that the insert function is not working although the edit and delete are working perfectly fine on the same page. This is the home2.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home2.aspx.cs" Inherits="DBPROJECT.Home2"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

  </head>
  <body style="background-image:url(img1.jpg)"  >
  <form id="form2" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="ab" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial"
HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"   
BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
     CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
OnRowEditing="ab_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="ab_RowCancelingEdit" 
OnRowDeleting="ab_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="ab_RowUpdating" 
EnableViewState="False" ><AlternatingRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registration Number" HeaderStyle-
HorizontalAlign="Left">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="aa" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reg_no") %>'></asp:Label>
</EditItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblItemNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reg_no") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name Of NGO" HeaderStyle-
HorizontalAlign="Left">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="bb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nname") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nname") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="cc"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalUnits" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OwnerID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="dd" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("owner_id") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblItemNoo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("owner_id") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
      <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" text="Enter the registration number" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="A1" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" text="Enter the name of NGO   " Font-Bold="True" 
        ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="A2" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server"  text="Enter the address   " Font-Bold="True" 
 ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="A3" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server"  text="Enter the owner's ID    " Font-Bold="True" 
        ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="A4" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<div>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Insert" ID="Button1"OnClick="Button1_Click"
            BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Maroon"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DBPROJECT.DAL;

namespace DBPROJECT
{
    public partial class Home2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        myDAL objMyDal = new myDAL();
        ab.DataSource = objMyDal.SelectItem(); 
         ab.DataBind();

    }
    protected void ab_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ab.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        LoadGrid();

    }

    protected void ab_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ab.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label a1 = (Label)ab.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("aa");
        TextBox a2 = (TextBox)ab.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("bb");
        TextBox a3 = (TextBox)ab.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("cc");
        Label a4 = (Label)ab.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dd");


        int reg_no = Convert.ToInt32(a1.Text.ToString());
        string nname = a2.Text.ToString();
        string address = a3.Text.ToString();
        int owner1 = Convert.ToInt32(a4.Text.ToString());

        myDAL objMyDal = new myDAL();
        objMyDal.UpdateItem(reg_no, nname, address);
         //   ======================================================
            ab.EditIndex = -1;
            LoadGrid();
    }

    protected void ab_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        myDAL objMyDal = new myDAL();
        GridViewRow row = ab.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label itemLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("lblItemNo");
        int ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(itemLabel.Text.ToString());
        int result = objMyDal.DeleteItem(ItemID);
        if (result == -1)
        {
            ab.DataSource = objMyDal.SelectItem();
            ab.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "No row deleted";
            ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(),"alert", message.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void ab_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ab.EditIndex = -1;
        LoadGrid();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
       int aa= Convert.ToInt32(A1.Text.ToString());
       string bb = A2.Text.ToString();
       string cc = A3.Text.ToString();
       int dd = Convert.ToInt32(A4.Text.ToString());
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Insert failed');</script>");
            myDAL objMyDal = new myDAL();
        objMyDal.insertItem(aa,bb,cc,dd,ref DT);
        LoadGrid();
    }
    }
}
```

The definition in the dal file is as follows

```
public int insertItem(int reg, string name, string add, int o1, ref DataTable DT)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd,cmd1;
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            //cmd1 = new SqlCommand("newNGO", con);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into NGO values (@reg_no,@nname,@address,@owner_id)", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@reg_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = reg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = add;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@owner_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = o1;
            /*

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = add;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@owner_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = o1;
            */
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The column names of the table are reg_no (int), nname(varchar), address(varchar) and owner_id(int). reg_no is the primary key and owner_id is foreign key.
I have been trying to find out the error since last week. Clicking the insert button does not throw any exception or error but it also does not insert the values in the database.

Comment: How insert is not working? Can you elaborate the specific problem that you are facing?

Comment: @mmushtaq i have posted the updated question

Comment: Did you debug your code, specifically button1_click event?

Comment: yes. it goes through and gives no error.

Comment: Your `NGO` table has four column and they are more or less than four?

Comment: it has 4 columns

Comment: What is the return value of `result` variable after the execution of method? As per my understanding, if data is not being inserted in table, then there should be some errors. Apply breakpoints in catch statements.

Comment: And wrap up your `LoadGrid` in Page_Load event with `if(!Page.IsPostBack){ LoadGrid() }` ;

Comment: I did that. There were no errors and the code run till the end

Comment: There is no change even after using PostBack

Comment: `reg_no` is identity column or not? Its value is set to auto incremented?

Comment: no it is not identity column. any value can be set

Comment: Then make sure you are not inserting duplicate value for it. And just a hint,specify your sql parameters using [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have done AddwithValue but there is no change. Also i am not adding any duplicate value. I have a signup page which adds the details of a new user to the database without any problem but this one is not being solved

Comment: return result shows 0 during debugging

Comment: already did that. there is no change.

Comment: I justed tested it in a console app. I have no issues inserting data. Are you sure there is values in all your params?

Comment: Yes. I debugged it a few times to check that the values were being picked up.

Comment: Try to hardcode your values. Just to see if they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

change cmd.Parameters.Add to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue and then try

Comment: eg : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_id", o1);

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_id", 100);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_id", "xyz");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_id", "XYZ Address");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_id", 20);

Comment: try this to pass the value manually and check it whether these values are inserted or not

Comment: please edit this info into your answer rather than leaving a comment

Comment: Yes. it inserted the values in cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue

Comment: it seems there is no problem in your table.so just check insert function, whether all the values are in their related datafields or not.

Comment: Still cant figure it out. Can you explain what do you mean by related datafields?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. The variable nname was set as varchar(20) and I was entering a string "Doctors without Borders" which is clearly larger than 20 and therefore it was throwing the exception. Thanks for your help and concerns.